# Token sale and one-time address

Tags: contract-design, tokens

On many token sale site I see workflow when user suggested to send ETH to one time address and it is changed each time I refreshing page. I am trying to understand how it implemented?

Only way I see is to have main contract that acts as factory that can create children contracts per request that only has fallback function that forwards incoming ETH, `msg.sender` and `msg.value` to the main one. But this approach looks insecure - each subcontract creation takes gas and I potentially can exhaust main contract only by refreshing site's page and asking each time for new pay-in address.

Could you explain how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is likely that this unnamed token sale doesn't use smart contracts at all.

For more information see this answer:

- [ICO crowdsale without smart contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/41913/ico-crowdsale-without-smart-contract/41924#41924)

Comment: Example: https://earth-token.com/affiliates.html